# CoreData Entity Updates at App Login

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

My app talk to webServer. At login, I pull down JSON and make up CoreData with 4 Entities (about 1000 rows each). The data changes on Server, So with every login, I have to update my existing CoreData. 
What is the best approach to find out if records exist and insert new ones if need be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be smart on update (not blindly update every time), you need some intelligence on the server side.

One idea I would do.

1. Server has master table that records the timestamp of modified date of the 4 entities. It also has API to expose the master table. Every time change occurs to one of the 4 entities, master table's corresponding entry has to be updated as well.
2. You create the same copy of master table in application side as well.
3. On application launch, you query API in 1. and compare with the value in 2. to see if the timestamp has updated on the server side.
4. If YES, then download and replace the corresponding entity.

Another one which allows finer control.

1. Add timestamp column to the 4 entities on the server side. Every time entry is added/updated, the timestamp is updated.
2. Prepare an API for each entity that filters only newer items than the specified timestamp
3. On application launch, you query API in 2. and update.

The hole of the second approach is that it cannot handle deletion on the server side. Maybe you can combine something like the first approach to support this.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, its not my webserver, I am talking to third party server. But, good suggestions, will keep that in mind.